# Handling file and text input field simultaneously in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, httprequest

I have a collection of file inputs and text inputs. Each file input has a corresponding type field. I need to retrieve both values as a list. Currently, I'd tried following:

**Controller code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public OutletIndex updateOutlet(@PathVariable String id,
                                @ModelAttribute @Valid OutletIndex outlet,
                                @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) List<MultipartFile> file,
                                @RequestParam(value = "types", required = false) List<MultipartFile> types,
                                HttpServletRequest request
) {
    //......
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text" name="types"/>
<input type="text" name="types"/>
<input type="text" name="types"/>
<input type="text" name="types"/>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

---

It's working well if file input selected any file. If we don't select any file it's not showing in the list but text input is showing even if it's empty. How can I resolve that?

I'd also tried to get value using `request.getParameterMap()`  but both ways result is same.

When I'd choose 2 files then the output would be like.

[image]

`types` list size is `4` and `file` list size is `2`.

Can I make it `null` in list if no file is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I'd resolved my problem by adding slight variation in *@RamanaManoj* answer using a POJO class. I'd added an additional POJO class which holds the list of `FileWrapper`.

---

**FileWrapper.java:**

```
public class FileWrapper {
    private MultipartFile file;

    private String types;

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public String getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public void setTypes(String types) {
        this.types = types;
    }
}
```

---

**FileWrappers.java:**

```
public class FileWrappers {
    private List<FileWrapper> fileWrappers=new ArrayList<>();

    public List<FileWrapper> getFileWrappers() {
        return fileWrappers;
    }

    public void setFileWrappers(List<FileWrapper> fileWrappers) {
        this.fileWrappers = fileWrappers;
    }
}
```

---

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public OutletIndex updateOutlet(@PathVariable String id,
                                @ModelAttribute("OutletIndex") @Valid OutletIndex outlet,
                                BindingResult resultOutlet,
                                @ModelAttribute("FileWrappers") FileWrappers fileWrappers,
                                BindingResult resultWrappersoutletImage
) {
   //....
}
```

---

**HTML Form fields:**

```
<input type="text" name="fileWrappers[0].types"/>
<input type="text" name="fileWrappers[1].types"/>
<input type="text" name="fileWrappers[3].types"/>
<input type="text" name="fileWrappers[4].types"/>
<input type="file" name="fileWrappers[0].file"/>
<input type="file" name="fileWrappers[1].file"/>
<input type="file" name="fileWrappers[2].file"/>
<input type="file" name="fileWrappers[3].file"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way for doing this would be to have POJO  map the file and text input .i am not sure what you are trying to achieve but this may help you..

## your pojo

```
public class FileWrapper {
private MultipartFile file;

private String type;

public MultipartFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public OutletIndex updateOutlet(@ModelAttribute List<FileWrapper> fileWrapper) {
    // ......

    for (FileWrapper file : fileWrapper) {

        if (file.getFile() != null && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(file.getType())) {
            // your logic
        }
    }

}
```

your jsp file

```
<form method="post" action="/file" modelAttribute="fileWrapper">
    <input type="text" name="types[0]" /> <input type="text"
        name="types[1]" /> <input type="text" name="types[2]" /> <input
        type="text" name="types[3]" /> <input type="file" name="file[0]" /> <input
        type="file" name="file[1]" /> <input type="file" name="file[2]" /> <input
        type="file" name="file[3]" />
</form>
```

this should be comfortable for you .may be give it a try .

Comment: Thanks a lot man... after creating an additional POJO class which holds the list of `FileWrapper` finally I got solved my problem :)